# Emails returned by hotmail

Tags: smtp, email

Some emails I send (from php) are returned by hotmail with this message:

```
<xxxxxxx@hotmail.com>:
User and password not set, continuing without authentication.
65.55.92.136 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
Giving up on 65.55.92.136.
```

I understand that the recipient has no mailbox. But what does that mean:

```
"User and password not set, continuing without authentication."
```

And what can I do to avoid it?

I use linux/qmail.

**EDIT :** I am not using hotmail to send emails. I am sending emails **to** some hotmail users.

Answer (score 1):

The e-mails doenst exist.

Answer (score 0):

You qmail servers SMTP route specification file does not contain a username/password line for mx1.hotmail.com/mx2.hotmail.com. You probably misconfigured SMTP AUTH with your relay host.

Comment: Actually I am not using hotmail. I am sending emails *to* some hotmail users. Hotmail is the only one displaying such a message.